# How to add custom sorting with multi meta key for Woocommerce in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I am working on the WooCommerce which the product comes with custom fields (Field's Name : year). And I want to make a custom sorting for my shop which the product should be sorting by Year and Then follow by the Highest Price.

For Example

- Product A is 2017 with $20
- Product B is 2017 with $25
- Product C is 2016 with $30

The Shop page should Order Like this
B . A . C

I have searched from many sources in the internet and I found some useful articles but I don't know that How to add multi meta_key to the query

Reference Links : http://dominykasgel.com/how-to-add-custom-product-sorting-options-in-woocommerce/

I see in the code

```
$args['meta_key'] = '_sale_price';
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$args['order'] = 'DESC';
```

Please anybody tell me for how to add more $args['meta_key'] and how to combine them to run the sorting work together? (more meta_key in my case is my custom field named 'year').

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In order to order by multiple meta values you need to use meta_query.
From the Wordpress CODEX:

If you wish to order by two different pieces of postmeta (for example, City first and State second), you need to combine and link your meta query to your orderby array using 'named meta queries'. See the example below:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'city_clause' => 'ASC',
        'state_clause' => 'DESC',
    ),
) );
```

So you need to add all yout order_clauses in the meta_query array...